# {"Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details."}

Tags: asp.net-mvc, binding, model

I have a Registration Class in which i have total 8 fields and all are required fields , Now I have another view for which i need to have the same model but in that view i just need four fields from the model so when saving it says model.isvalid is false because it need all four properties as in model class i have set the required field . 
now for another view i am using this code to remove the other un-nessary properties

but still i am getting the error Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
When i check DbEntityValidationException detail it says the password is required althoguh in above code  i have deleted the password from model using   ModelState.Remove("Password"); but it still says password is required field when i check DbentityValidationException detail

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "User_Id,IsActive,Email_Address,Username,Gender_Id,Department_Id")] Registration registration)
        {
            ModelState.Remove("FirstName");
            ModelState.Remove("LastName");
            ModelState.Remove("ReportingManager");
            ModelState.Remove("ResetPasswordCode");
            ModelState.Remove("Mobile");
            ModelState.Remove("Password");
            ModelState.Remove("ConfirmPassword");
            ModelState.Remove("Status");
            ModelState.Remove("DOB");
            ModelState.Remove("DOJ");
            ModelState.Remove("Created_Date");
            ModelState.Remove("Modified_Date");
            ModelState.Remove("City_Id");
            ModelState.Remove("Designation_Id");
            ModelState.Remove("User_Type_Id");
            ModelState.Remove("Photo");
            ModelState.Remove("Remember_Token");
            ModelState.Remove("Country_ID");
            ModelState.Remove("City_Id");
            ModelState.Remove("Qualification");
            ModelState.Remove("CNIC");
            ModelState.Remove("BasicSalary");
            ModelState.Remove("FavouriteSubjects");
            ModelState.Remove("Annual_Increment");
            ModelState.Remove("Home_address");
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(registration).State = EntityState.Modified;
                try
                {
                    db.SaveChanges();

                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }


                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.City_Id = new SelectList(db.Cities, "City_Id", "City_Name", registration.City_Id);
            ViewBag.Country_ID = new SelectList(db.Countries, "Country_ID", "Name", registration.Country_ID);
            ViewBag.Department_Id = new SelectList(db.Departments, "Department_Id", "Department_Title", registration.Department_Id);
            ViewBag.Designation_Id = new SelectList(db.Designations, "Designation_Id", "Designation_Text", registration.Designation_Id);
            ViewBag.Gender_Id = new SelectList(db.Genders, "Gender_Id", "Name", registration.Gender_Id);
            ViewBag.User_Type_Id = new SelectList(db.User_Types, "User_Type_Id", "Title", registration.User_Type_Id);
            return View(registration);
        }
```

It should remove the password as well from model as i do not need it as required for this view

Comment: Do not expose your domain model directly to the user.  Use separate view models that map back to your domain.

Comment: Thanks Fran I appreciate the right way you told me but the way i am doing it is another way i am afraid as you see i am removing the password from entity model but why it is still giving the error that password is required field !